# Longest parked vehicle

Tags: java

I have arrayList of objects:

```
private ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>()
```

When user inputs all the details to add vehicle, he inputs the date and time:
***Example Input:***
Enter date: DD/MM/YYYY
13/11/2016
Enter time: HH:MM
10:00

The array has capacity of 20 objects so there is more than one input, the date and time are inputed as strings. How do I display the vehicle that was parked the longest time? I have something like this but it wont work at all.

```
        long longest =  0;
        for (Vehicle vehicle : vehicles){
            long hours = vehicle.getDateTime().hours();
            if (hours > longest){
                longest = hours;

            }

       }
```

Comment: Haven't you asked this before? Also, *wont work at all* doesn't help anyone. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work?

Comment: You should maybe move your _println_'s to after the loop, otherwise they'll  most likely get called a number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the longest outside the loop, not everytime you find a longer one

```
    long longest =  Long.MIN_VALUE;
    Vehicle v = null;
    for (Vehicle vehicle : vehicles){
        long hours = vehicle.getDateTime().hours();
        if (hours > longest){
            longest = hours; 
            v = vehicle;
        }
    }

    if (v!=null) {
        System.out.println("Longest Parked Vehicle is:");
        System.out.println(v);
    }
```

And, implement a toString method for the Vehicle class!

Comment: thanks i was missing the last part, solved after so many hours, thanks again.

Comment: Try to use a debugger next time ;)